# Getting an element not found exception from an exception handler

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting element not found exception while trying to locate the element in a try loop. Below is my code:

```js
private  boolean isPresent(WebDriver driver,String findElement)
  {
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   try {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(findElement));
    return true;
   }
   catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return false;
   }
     finally{
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Remove all instances of implicit waits... does it still throw?

Comment: @JeffC. thank you for your reply. By removing the implicitWait instances, you mean from the main method? because i would be needing the implicitWait there as there are many other elements that would require waiting to locate them.

Comment: Implicit waits are set once for the driver instance so setting it repeatedly does nothing. Yes, remove all instances and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to do this is to avoid throwing exceptions in the first place.

```
private boolean isPresent(WebDriver driver, By locator)
{
    return !driver.findElements(locator).isEmpty();
}
```

Instead of passing the locator as string and requiring XPath, use a `By` locator. Now you can pass the method any locator type... Id, CSS selector, etc.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm. But I am still not able to figure out why it was throwing the error from exception handlers. Anyways will look into it later.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using find element and timeouts use some waits or until for the element to be present and then do the operation.
eg. This will wait until the element is located, then do what you want to do with your myDynamicELement

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myElement")));
```

It looks like you are trying to validate whether your element is present or not. For that use a logic something like this.
A) Inside try
1) Wait for the element to be present
2) Then Use if then else to check if element present and return true or false
B) Inside Catch handle the error.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for helping me out. I had earlier tried using the explicit wait, but I hadn't used the presenceOfElementLocated. This should have worked. But I am not able to figure out the problem. Anyways, the below answer worked perfect for me. Thank you once again for taking your time and helping me out here.